# Alternative to java.nio.file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, io, java.nio.file

I'm using Android Studio 2.3.1 and jdk 1.8 for this project.

I import a project and it's using 'java.nio.file.Files' and 'java.nio.file.Paths'.

Package "java.nio.file" does not exist in Java 8.

Also Android Studio does not allow to select jdk 1.7.

What can i do with this code ?

```
public void toFile(final String path) throws IOException {
    Files.write(Paths.get(path), toBuffer());
}
```

and this code

```
public static Source fromFile(final String path) throws IOException {
    return fromBuffer(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
}
```

** (Cannot resolve Files and Paths)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Good news: java.nio.* in now part of Android O!

More information here https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

Android does not offer all classes that "conventional Java" has to offer. Files are one of the classes, that Android doesn't offer.

You can have a look at the classes available in Android here: http://developer.android.com/reference/classes.html

So, unfortunately, you have to use other functions/classes to implement the same functionality.

I found this [library](https://github.com/lukhnos/nnio) that claims to be

> NNIO: A Java NIO.2 Substitute Library

but I think you should use instead [guava](https://github.com/google/guava) to implement the same functionality, as it is used in many first-class apps and has a big community.

**Edit:**
As Android O Developer Preview  java.nio.file is supported.
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/package-summary.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this library have Paths class like same class in java.nio.file but NNIO have Files class that does not have 'write' and 'readallbytes' method !!

Comment: then you should take a look at guava. I'm pretty sure that you can accomplish the same with very similar code.

Comment: Yes, Guava have 'toByteArray' method that work same as 'readAllBytes' but I could not work with it. Can you write my project methods again with Guava and NNIO ?

Comment: I tried to rewrite methods with Guava library (yesterday) but my project did not work properly.