# Java android AsynchronousSocketChannel

Tags: java, android

How I can use AsynchronousSocketChannel in anroid i can not import

```
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler;
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43706821/1083957) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's available only from 26 API ([proof](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html)). Make sure your minimum SDK is >= 26